# Add values to an existing dataframe from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe containing two empty columns in it. I have below list of tuples:

```
l = [('l1', 0.966797), ('l1', 0.998047), ('l2', 0.978516), ('l2', 0.998047), ('l3', 0.972656)]
```

I want to add these values to the two empty columns of dataframe. One way I know is to create a dataframe of the list like below

```
d = pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['s','p'])
```

But it will create a new dataframe, I need to add those values into an existing dataframe. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use double `[]` with columns names, [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':range(5)})
print (df)
   column
0       0
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4

l = [('l1', 0.966797), ('l1', 0.998047), 
     ('l2', 0.978516), ('l2', 0.998047), ('l3', 0.972656)]
```

---

```
df[['s','p']] = pd.DataFrame(l)

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['s','p']))

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(l,columns=['s','p'])], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
   column   s         p
0       0  l1  0.966797
1       1  l1  0.998047
2       2  l2  0.978516
3       3  l2  0.998047
4       4  l3  0.972656
```